# rails, sorting mongoid children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, sql-order-by, mongoid

I'm having a problem sorting with mongoid.  I'm using voteable_mongo to collect votes on a given object and now I'd like to order based on those but I'm not having any luck:

It gives a field like so on a model and has a method called `votes_point`:

```
{"count"=>1, "down"=>[BSON::ObjectId('4f450fd725ae0b7538000002')], "down_count"=>1, "point"=>-1, "up"=>[], "up_count"=>0}
```

Code:

```
@word.definitions.order_by([:votes_point]).each do |definition|
```

or

```
@word.definitions.order_by([:votes["point"],:desc]).each do |definition|
```

The above statement doesn't order them any differently based on the votes.  It outputs exactly the same as `@word.definitions`

I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact I'm trying to order by the children of another model?  Must I query it more directly or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try:

```
@word.definitions.order_by('votes.point')
```

or

```
@word.definitions.order_by([['votes.point', :desc]])
```